# Where to change settings in Xcode for 'Save For Enterprise Deployment' archives

Tags: ios, xcode

I am building for Enterprise Deployment and would like have more control on where my ipas are saved and how the build folders are named.

Currently all builds are sent to my desktop. Each build is saved in a  '$(PRODUCT_NAME) +  YYYY-mm-dd hh-mm-ss' format.

Is it possible to change the destination of the build to a relative location to the workspace? Am i able to change the folder to a format that reflects the build version?

I am on XCode 7.0.1 (7A1001) OSX 10.10.5 (14F27)

Answer (score 0):

Change in Xcode Preference.But I can't find how to set $(PROJECT)....
[image]

Comment: Yes, i looked into the preferences too. But I am looking to set the location and the name for the ipa that is generated from the archive.  If i set the 'Archives' location in preferences to any other location, i still get the ipa folder and build on the desktop.